# Как правильно сформировать многопоточность?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

подскажите, пожалуйста, как лучше сделать в моем случае. Хочу распараллелить задачи, но получается только с 1 потоком. Постоянно нужно ждать когда получу результат d (future.get()). А можно как-то сделать так, чтобы поток который ждет результат оставался ждать, а другой поток продолжал дальше по циклу выполнять свою работу?

```
        List<Integer> index = new ArrayList<>();
        ///....///
        List<List<Integer>> dis = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < links.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (index.get(i) == 0) {
                ..////...
                List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = i + 1; j < links.size(); j++) {

                        URL oneURL = new URL(links.get(i));           
                        URL twoURL = new URL(links.get(j));
                        Task task = new Task(oneURL, twoURL);
                        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
                        Future<Double> future = executor.submit(task);
                        Double d = future.get();
                        executor.shutdown();
                        if (d > k) {
                            list.add(j);
                            index.set(j, 1);
                        }
                }
                dis.add(list);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Прошу прощения. А что дальше должно выполняться? у вас все зависит от этого самого `get()`. Вы хотите сделать поток->поток->поток->поток ? Аналог рекурсии? В противном случае, делайте ваш Future на весь второй `for()` Либо попробуйте сделать черезе `parallelStream()`

Comment: @Dred java 7 (android разработка)

Comment: Не в этом вопрос. Вопрос в том, что у вас поток дошел до `Double d = future.get();`  и ждет выполнения задачи. А что должен основной поток выполнять?  Сейчас у вас нет ничего, что могло бы выполняться, у вас всё зависит от `d` .Вы может попробовать сделать  `ExecutorService` после первого `for()` и на каждый `i` внутри  второго `for()`  вызывать всю вашу логику `URL oneURL......` которая будет в отдельном методе. Тогда у вас будет хоть что-то... что будет выполняться параллельно. Если я правильно понимаю то, что вы хотите. Если нет, то дополните, пожалуйста, вопрос.

Comment: @dead хотелось бы чтобы он дальше по циклу продолжал работу. а не ждал .get()

Comment: тогда вызывай поток без get, а в PostExecute выполняй if (d > k)...

Comment: @ВладимирМалахов вы имеете в виду асинк таск использовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал так:

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
List<CompletableFuture<Boolean>> completableFutures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    completableFutures.add(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        //some work
        return true;
    }, executorService));
}

for (final CompletableFuture<Boolean> completableFuture : completableFutures) {
    try {
        boolean result = completableFuture.get(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        System.out.println("is done: " + result);
    } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
        completableFuture.cancel(true);
    }
}

executorService.shutdownNow();
```

Comment: у меня 7 джава( для андроида же пишу)

Comment: но идея в принципе понятна, спасибо

Comment: огромное вам спасибо, немного правда по другому сделала. но за идею спасибо

Comment: @ArtemKonovalov, у меня вопрос. Подскажите, пожалуйста, если бы в `for` `i<1_000_000` было? Что в итоге происходит? сначала создается громадный список, а потом программа заново проходится по всему этому списку из млн элементов и выполняет их? Разве это не последовательное выполнение?

Comment: Нет, там не будет последовательного выполнения. Команда `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` отправляет лямбду функцию в очередь выполнения тред пула и возвращать некоторый объект `CompletableFuture` из которого можно достать результат выполнения(если функция выполнилась) и/или статус выполнения и прочее. Тред пул выполняет поступающие задачи в разных потоках, одновременно. В цикле где происходит итерирование по `CompletableFuture`, мы лишь достаем результат выполнения